# get_footer hook is calling twice in my wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am new in wordpress development.
I made a plugin and inside it i am calling get_footer hook. But it is being called twice.
Here is my sample code.

```
function Show_Welcome_Message()
{
global $pagename;
    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_name = ucwords($user->display_name);
        setcookie("mcf_returning_user", $user_name, time() + (86400*30), "/");
    }
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && !empty($_COOKIE['mcf_returning_user']) && empty($_COOKIE['mcf_welcome_back_msg_later']))
    {
        if(!is_front_page())
        {
            echo "Not home";
            $template_url = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)."templates/prompt-message.php";
            include $template_url;
            setcookie("mcf_welcome_back_msg_later", "1", time() + 3600, "/");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "home";
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'get_footer', 'Show_Welcome_Message' );
```

Note :- Both 'home' and 'not home', both conditions are executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to changes the if condition
Replace this

```
if(!is_front_page())
```

with the below code

```
if(!is_home() && !is_front_page())
```